# start from first line in each iteration

Tags: java, iteration

i  am reading two file. my code is given below:

```
BufferedReader comone = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\xml_one.txt"));
BufferedReader comtwo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\xml_two.txt"));

int a = 0;          
String one;
String two;

while ((one = comone.readLine()) != null) { 

        a= -111111;
        while ((two = comtwo.readLine()) != null) { 


        if(one.equals(two) == false)
            {
                a =1;
            }
        else
            {
                a=0;
                break;

            }               
        }

        if(a==1)
        {   
            System.out.println("Check this name : "+one);
        }   
    }
```

in my code i read two file. But problem is i want to read the second file( in 2nd while) every time from first line. but currently my code read first line in first iteration, than again start from 2nd line in 2nd iteration. i want to read from first line also in 2nd that means in each iteration(2nd file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mark the beginning of `comtwo` and then after your second while, call `comtwo.reset()` so you would get something like:

```
while ((one = comone.readLine()) != null) { 

    a= -111111;
    comtwo.mark(someInt); // basically just the length you expect to read in comtwo
    while ((two = comtwo.readLine()) != null) { 


    if(one.equals(two) == false)
        {
            a =1;
        }
    else
        {
            a=0;
            break;

        }               
    }
    comtwo.reset();

    if(a==1)
    {   
        System.out.println("Check this name : "+one);
    }   
}
```

This should return your `BufferedReader` to the mark, a.k.a. the first line, after the loop.

Eran's answer would also work, but that would result in a file open operation in every iteration, which creates an IO overhead. Whereas mark just creates a memory overhead.

Comment: thanks a lot and this works for me .... actually i am looking for this kind of solution because if i add  BufferedReader comtwo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\xml_two.txt")); at beginning of while loop it creates problem.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Windows, because that OS locks files once they are opened, which would explain why it creates problems.. If you were to open the file anew, then you would have to close the previous link to it first.